# Iterate a list with indexes

Tags: python, list

I could swear I've seen the function (or method) that takes a list, like this `[3, 7, 19]` and makes it into iterable list of tuples, like so: `[(0,3), (1,7), (2,19)]` to use it instead of:

```
for i in range(len(name_of_list)):
    name_of_list[i] = something
```

but I can't remember the name and googling "iterate list" gets nothing.

Answer (score 394, accepted):

```
>>> a = [3,4,5,6]
>>> for i, val in enumerate(a):
...     print i, val
...
0 3
1 4
2 5
3 6
>>>
```

Answer (score 112):

Yep, that would be the [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate) function! Or more to the point, you need to do:

```
list(enumerate([3,7,19]))

[(0, 3), (1, 7), (2, 19)]
```

Comment: sometimes people ask a question related to the one they really want, other times, they are somewhat indiscriminate about what "best" means.

Comment: And sometimes people only read the first one and a half lines of the question instead of the whole question. If you get to the end of the second line he says he wants to use it instead of `for i in range(len(name_of_list)):` which is what led me to provide an example using a for instead of what was shown in the first part.

Comment: @HumphreyBogart  Because Lauren Bacall likes being more verbose.

Answer (score 26):

Here's another using the `zip` function.

```
>>> a = [3, 7, 19]
>>> zip(range(len(a)), a)
[(0, 3), (1, 7), (2, 19)]
```

Comment: `enumerate()` is a bit more elegant, I think.

Comment: @Nathan: But zip() is more general and works for arbitrary pairs of lists, so it's good to know.

Comment: `zip` lets you put the values the other way around, in cases where that leads to a clearer overall algorithm.

Answer (score 8):

Here it is a solution using map function:

```
>>> a = [3, 7, 19]
>>> map(lambda x: (x, a[x]), range(len(a)))
[(0, 3), (1, 7), (2, 19)]
```

And a solution using list comprehensions:

```
>>> a = [3,7,19]
>>> [(x, a[x]) for x in range(len(a))]
[(0, 3), (1, 7), (2, 19)]
```

Answer (score 5):

python `enumerate` function will be satisfied  your requirements

```
result = list(enumerate([1,3,7,12]))
print result
```

**output**

```
[(0, 1), (1, 3), (2, 7),(3,12)]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have multiple lists, you can do this combining `enumerate` and `zip`:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
list2 = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
list3 = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500]
for i, (l1, l2, l3) in enumerate(zip(list1, list2, list3)):
    print(i, l1, l2, l3)
```

Output:

```
0 1 10 100
1 2 20 200
2 3 30 300
3 4 40 400
4 5 50 500
```

Note that parenthesis is required after `i`. Otherwise you get the error: `ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack`