# Which is the most efficient way to iterate through a list in python?

Tags: python, performance, list

Say I have a list of items:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I need to perform some functions for each of these items. In a certain case, I need to return the index of an item.

Which is the best and most efficient way?

```
for item in list:
    ....
```

or

```
for i in range(len(list)):
    ....
```

Comment: please search the forum beofre posting. This has been answered a million times

Comment: possible duplicate of [Iterate a list with indexes in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/126524/iterate-a-list-with-indexes-in-python)

Comment: @sulabh: I fail to find the exact duplicate of this question. Please link the same. The question here i'm asking is a comparison between two different ways of iterating a list, and a suggestion of which is better.

Comment: if this is not an exact duplicate then can people take back their downvotes please? i'm a poor person, you see...

Comment: I would warn against a possible misconception that lists are efficient containers. They are not. If you plan to iterate over large datasets lists are not efficient. See below, should use numpy arrays which are less flexible but can handle size.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
for item in list:
```

its obviously the one with fewer function calls.

If you want to get the index of items as you go use [enumerate](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate) like this

```
for pos, item in enumerate(collection):
```

Answer (score 29):

```
def loop_1(data):
    for i in range(len(data)):
        print(data[i])


def looper_2(data):
    for val in data:
        print(val)
```

Checking with [dis](http://docs.python.org/library/dis.html) gives us the following bytecode for loop_1:

```
 12       0 SETUP_LOOP              40 (to 43)
          3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (range)
          6 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (len)
          9 LOAD_FAST                0 (data)
         12 CALL_FUNCTION            1
         15 CALL_FUNCTION            1
         18 GET_ITER            
    >>   19 FOR_ITER                20 (to 42)
         22 STORE_FAST               1 (i)

13       25 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (print)
         28 LOAD_FAST                0 (data)
         31 LOAD_FAST                1 (i)
         34 BINARY_SUBSCR       
         35 CALL_FUNCTION            1
         38 POP_TOP             
         39 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           19
    >>   42 POP_BLOCK           
    >>   43 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
         46 RETURN_VALUE
```

The bytecode for loop_2 looks like this:

```
17        0 SETUP_LOOP              24 (to 27)
          3 LOAD_FAST                0 (data)
          6 GET_ITER            
    >>    7 FOR_ITER                16 (to 26)
         10 STORE_FAST               1 (val)

18       13 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (print)
         16 LOAD_FAST                1 (val)
         19 CALL_FUNCTION            1
         22 POP_TOP             
         23 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            7
    >>   26 POP_BLOCK           
    >>   27 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
         30 RETURN_VALUE
```

The second version is obviously better.

Answer (score 5):

Another possible solution would be to use `numpy` which would be very efficient, for large lists perhaps even more efficient than a list comprehension or a for loop.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(5.0)   # a --> array([0., 1., 2., 3., 4.])

# numpy operates on arrays element by element 
#
b =3.*a              # b --> array([0., 3., 6., 9., 12.])
```

This is a pretty simple operation but you can get more complex using an array as simply an argument in a formula.  For large arrays this can be much faster than a list comprehension and it makes the code cleaner and easier to read (no need to create a function to map in a list comprehension).   You can also use indexing and slicing to tailor what you want to do:

If you want to have access to the actual index positions use ndenumerate

```
# b is as above
for i, x in np.ndenumerate(b):
    print i, x
```

The output of this for loop is:

```
(0,) 0.0 
(1,) 3.0 
(2,) 6.0 
(3,) 9.0 
(4,) 12.0
```

NOTE: the index returned as a tuple by numpy to handle additional dimensions.  Here we only have a single dimension so you'd have to unpack the tuple to get the index of the element.

Comment: Can you add any details about this?

Answer (score 4):

Obviously `for i in range(len(list)):` will be slower - in python 2, it's equivalent to this:

```
list2 = range(len(list))

for i in list2:
    ...
```

If that were faster, then this would be even faster, right?

```
list2 = range(len(list))
list3 = range(len(list2))
list4 = range(len(list3))

for i in list4:
    ...
```