# Add multiple values to a dictionary key

Tags: python, list, dictionary, data-structures

I have two lists:

```
list1 = ['670', '619', '524', '670', '693', '693', '693', '632', '671']
list2 = ['JAIPUR', 'MUMBAI', 'DELHI', 'UDAIPUR', 'GOA', 'GOA', 'GOA', 'LUCKNOW', 'JAIPUR']
```

I want to make a dictionary out of this.
Please note the two lists exactly in the order that it should be mapped into. Like for key '670' value us 'JAIPUR' and so on.

But when I tried, it gives output as:

```
d = dict(zip(list1, list2))

{'670': 'UDAIPUR', '619': 'MUMBAI', '524': 'DELHI', '693': 'GOA', '632': 'LUCKNOW', '671': 'JAIPUR'}
```

It takes only the latest value if multiple values are found for a single key.
However what I want is multiple values for a single key like 670 should have:

```
'670': ['JAIPUR', 'UDAIPUR']
```

Can anyone help.

Comment: `dict` objects associate key-value pairs where the keys are unique. However, your values can be containers themselves, so, for example a `list` or a `tuple`.

Comment: Is there a logic? In the example shared, you have equal number of elements in list1 and list2.

Comment: How would you determine which element(s) from `list2` should be mapped to each key from `list1`? Update your question and you might get more helpful answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `defaultdict` :

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> for i,key in enumerate(list1): 
        if list2[i] not in d[key]:            #to add only unique values (ex: '693':'goa')
            d[key].append(list2[i]) 

>>> d
=> defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'670': ['JAIPUR', 'UDAIPUR'], '619': ['MUMBAI'], 
               '524': ['DELHI'], '693': ['GOA'], '632': ['LUCKNOW'], '671': ['JAIPUR']})
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Also removes any duplicate values. Perfect ! Thank you

Comment: @VinnyKaur : glad to help

Comment: @mrCarnivore : `defaultdict` is nothing but a wrapper around `dict` , and so it offers a few extra functionalities, but all its basic structuring from `dict` are intact too.

Comment: @KaushikNP  can you please explain the part `enumerate(list1)` does here

Comment: @VinnyKaur : its used to access both `Index` along with the `elements` when iterating over the `list` here. You could go through : [Iterate a list with indexes in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126524/iterate-a-list-with-indexes-in-python/126533#126533) for better example on how its used.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is grouping by the `list1` items. Use `collections.defaultdict` object:

```
import collections

list1 = ['670', '619', '524', '670', '693', '693', '693', '632', '671']
list2 = ['JAIPUR', 'MUMBAI', 'DELHI', 'UDAIPUR', 'GOA', 'GOA', 'GOA', 'LUCKNOW', 'JAIPUR']
result = collections.defaultdict(list)

for t in zip(list1, list2):
    result[t[0]].append(t[1])

print(dict(result))
```

The output:

```
{'524': ['DELHI'], '671': ['JAIPUR'], '632': ['LUCKNOW'], '670': ['JAIPUR', 'UDAIPUR'], '619': ['MUMBAI'], '693': ['GOA', 'GOA', 'GOA']}
```

Comment: how does it identify list1 as t[0] and list2 as t[1]. Apologies if the question sounds silly, but python is new for me.

Comment: @VinnyKaur, `zip()` function generates a list/generator of tuples where each tuple contains consecutive values from all passed iterables, like `(670, 'JAIPUR'), (619, 'MUMBAI') ...`

Answer (score 0):

Since dicts can not have more than one element with the same key the newer values for that key that are assigned to a dict overwrite the older ones.

So with this code it works:

```
list1 = ['670', '619', '524', '670', '693', '693', '693', '632', '671']
list2 = ['JAIPUR', 'MUMBAI', 'DELHI', 'UDAIPUR', 'GOA', 'GOA', 'GOA', 'LUCKNOW', 'JAIPUR']

def extendDictValue(d, key, value):
    if key in d:
        d[key].append(value)
    else:
        d[key] = [value]

d={}
for key, value in zip(list1, list2):
    extendDictValue(d, key, value)

print(d)
```