# How can I print the first name?

Tags: python

```
name = ['Marina Allison', 'Markus Valdez', 'Connie Ballard', 'Darnell Weber', 'Sylvie Charles', 'Vinay Padilla', 'Meredith Santiago', 'Andre Mccarty', 'Lorena Hodson', 'Isaac Vu']

# how can I get the first name for ex. Marina
```

Name is the list of random names.
I've tried joining it with .join()

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterate a list with indexes in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126524/iterate-a-list-with-indexes-in-python)

Comment: What do you imagine are the logical steps to solving the problem? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try in this way:

```
name = ['Marina Allison', 'Markus Valdez', 'Connie Ballard', 'Darnell Weber', 'Sylvie Charles', 'Vinay Padilla', 'Meredith Santiago', 'Andre Mccarty', 'Lorena Hodson', 'Isaac Vu']

for i in name:
    print(i.split(' ')[0])
```

Comment: @Aaron Merchant can you accept the answer if it helped you. Thank you

Comment: yeh sure i can accept in 8 mins according to website, I'm new to python and all so thank you for helping

Answer (score 2):

Your question is somewhat ambiguous, so I'll provide an answer for the interpretations I find most obvious.

Firstly, given a full-name string `name = "First Last"`, I would recommend these approaches to getting just the `First` portion of the string:

1. Find the space and splice the string. This is arguably the most efficient method.

```
first_name = name[:name.find(" ")]
```

In Python, strings are character lists. `name.find(" ")` returns the index of the first occurrence of `" "`. Using this index, we splice the string and take only its characters preceding the space.

2. Split at the space and select the first element.

```
first_name = name.split()[0]   # split at whitespace, take first element
```

`split()` with no specified input argument splits on all white space, including spaces, newlines, carriage returns, etc, and returns a list of the elements separated by each of these whitespace characters. This is less efficient than the first solution but more concise.

Now, to apply this on the entire `name` list to obtain a list of only the first names, I offer these two code snippets:

First, the more straightforward approach

```py
first_names = []
for elem in name:
    first_names.append(elem[:elem.find(" ")])
```

Next, using functional programming tools

```py
first_names = list(map(lambda x: x[:x.find(" ")], name))
```

To print the result of either of these:

```py
print("\n".join(first_names))
```

or

```py
for x in first_names:
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension, one can  get first name as list:

[x.split()[0] for x in name]
o/p:
['Marina',
'Markus',
'Connie',
'Darnell',
'Sylvie',
'Vinay',
'Meredith',
'Andre',
'Lorena',
'Isaac']

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).